# Creating asynchronous thread for REST API processing using Spring Servet

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, asynchronous, fire-and-forget

I want to create fire-and-forget model for couple of my REST API calls where server will accept requests on end point, send object for async processing to internal services while releasing client connection. I am using Spring 3 MVC and Tomcat 6. I think introducing full messaging system like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ would be overkill for my project at this stage. 
Is there any other safe way for creating async processing (threads) for my services inside tomcat and Spring? I am afraid that doing thread programming inside tomcat will violate it integrity. 
Thanks

Comment: I have found interesting article on the related topic - about threading and concurrency in EJB    http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20120708/?pg=59&pm=1&u1=friend#pg59

Answer (score 3):

i am not sure weather you can use  @Async on controller but you can [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/scheduling.html) in service and invoke that from your controller.

yes regarding using thread in tomcat is not a good solution.